# The 100 Kauravs were incarnations of Asuras but what about their sister?

Tags: mahabharata, rebirth, asuras, kauravas

The **[Sambhava Parva of Mahabharat](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm)** gives the details of the who's who in Mahabharat and who were they the incarnations of. It has been covered at many places but my question is specific to **Dhritrashtra**'s progeny.

> The evil-minded and wicked king Duryodhana, the destroyer of the fair fame of the Kurus, was born of a portion of Kali on earth. He it was who caused all creatures to be slain and the earth to be wasted; and he it was who fanned the flame of hostility that ultimately consumed all. They who had been the sons of Pulastya (the Rakshasas) were born on earth among men of Duryodhana's brothers, that century of wicked individuals commencing with Duhasasana as their first. And, O bull among the Bharata princes, Durmukha, Duhsaha, and others whose names I do not mention, who always supported Duryodhana (in all his schemes), were, indeed, the sons of Pulastya. And over and above these hundred, Dhritarashtra had one son named Yuyutsu born of a Vaisya wife.'

I am not sure if Yuyutsu was also one of the Asura re-incarnations but my question is about the only daughter of Dhritrashtra whose previous birth is not mentioned:

> **There was also a daughter named Duhsala who was over and above the hundred.** And Yuyutsu who was Dhritarashtra's son by a Vaisya wife, was also over and above the hundred. Thus, O king, have I recited the names of the hundred sons and also that of the daughter (of Dhritarashtra)...... And, O king, when the time came, the **Kaurava monarch bestowed his daughter Duhsala on Jayadratha, the king of the Sindhus,** agreeably to the counsels of Sakuni.

So my question is - **Who was Duhsala, the only sister of the Asura reincarnate Kaurav brothers, a rebirth of?**

Comment: **Side note**: I think Kaurava-s were reincarnation of 1 or more Rakshasa. Rakshasa (or Daitya, DAnava) are more likely to be Asura, but are not exactly Asura. E.g. king Bali, Prahalad, Ghatotkacha etc were not Asura. Asura technically means, the one who likes [any kind of] bondage of world and don't tend to liberate. Opposite of that is Daiva.

Comment: Please protect this question, anybody.